# sqljdbc4 driver not returning resultSet from preceding insert from SQL Server 2012

Tags: jdbc, sql-server-2012, spring-jdbc

Our problem is that when the "execute" method is called from spring-jdbc (From the SqlQuery class) that returns a rowset in a List, the resultSet  is not returned and throws an exception. However, the insert happens just fine. We discovered that when we use a Merlia driver (an old one, even) that it works with SQL 2012. I believe I have configured something incorrectly because sqljdbc4.jar driver is not working with SQL server 2012, but works with SQL server 2008.
The stacktrace we see is:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:408)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:648)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:591)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:641)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:698)
org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlQuery.execute(SqlQuery.java:112)
org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlQuery.execute(SqlQuery.java:122)
ident.shared.dao.DAO.create(DAO.java:135)
ident.shared.business.BaseBusiness.create(BaseBusiness.java:57)
org.apache.jsp.add_005fnew_005fuser_jsp._jspService(add_005fnew_005fuser_jsp.java:538)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

By the way, I did try updating the spring-jdbc jar to at least 3.1.4 with no luck.

We have a JNDI connection established to SQl server 2012. Here is the part from context.xml.

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/Ident" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      username="*****" password="*****"
      driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://*******\dev;databaseName=ident" 
      maxActive="50"
      maxIdle="10">
</Resource>
```

Here is the connecting portion from the application's web.xml.

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/Ident</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Here is a method that lets you establish a connection.

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        Context extContext = (Context) context.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) extContext.lookup("jdbc/Ident");
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection was unable to be established.");
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Here is the code that inserts and calls the "execute" method from spring-jdbc. By the way, IdQuery extends "MappingSqlQuery", which extends org.springframework.jdbc.object.MappingSqlQueryWithParameters, which in turn extends SqlQuery, which defines the "execute" method the the IdQuery object calls.

```
public DataObject create(DataObject data)
{       

    IdQuery idq = new IdQuery(dataSource, this);
    List idList = idq.execute(this.getCreateParameters(data));
    if (idList != null && idList.size() > 0 && !idList.get(0).equals(new Integer(0))) {
        data.setId((Integer)idList.get(0));
    }

    return data;
}
```

Here is the constructor for IdQuery, if it helps.

```
class IdQuery extends MappingSqlQuery {

    IdQuery(DataSource ds, DAO dao) {
        super(ds,"somesql");
        dao.prepareCreate(this);
        super.setSql(this.getSql() + " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as ID");
        compile();
    }

    protected Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return (rs.getInt("ID"));
    }

}
```

Comment: So where is the code that inserts the data and tries to obtain the generated keys?

Comment: Edited to put that code in.

Comment: That is not JDBC code. You need to show what `IdQuery.execute` does, so we can check if it actually correctly uses the generated keys query facility. You also need to include the stacktrace of the exception. Looking at the definition of `MappingSqlQuery`, I don't think it is intended to execute generated keys queries. So it probably tries to get the normal result set (which doesn't exist) instead of the generated keys result set.

Comment: IdQuery extends MappingSqlQuery, which extends org.springframework.jdbc.object.MappingSqlQueryWithParameters<T>, which in turn extends SqlQuery, which defines the execute method. I added the constructor on for IdQuery, not sure if that helps though.

Comment: Updated to include stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are correct, I misspoke. It is supposed to return a resultSet in a list, not the generated Key directly. We are simply just grabbing the first entry in the list as the ID.

Comment: The fact that you concatenate a select to an existing query is probably the largest part of the problem (although I would expect a different exception). I'd suggest that you use the standard JDBC facility for retrieving generated keys (which with spring-jdbc involves using [`GeneratedKeyHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/GeneratedKeyHolder.html))

Comment: I would agree with you that it is not a very good way to get that Id back. I guess my main question is why this would break on a SQL server 2012 database but not a 2008 one, and why merlia is fine with it. I will take a look at that string concatenation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Although my initial question about still remains a mystery, we refactored our library to use the GeneratedKeyHolder as you suggested and it is working.

Comment: @jcd At minimum you might need to add a `;` between the queries, however - looking at the JDBC spec - a single statement execute should only execute one statement. It is also possible that the problem is with the ordering of update counts and result sets as returned from the server (maybe 2012 returns update count -> result set, where 2008 returned result set -> update count, but that is just speculation).